# Can i Split my php codes?

Tags: php

I have a php file with 1000+ lines of code.I am planning to split it using include_once() function (index.php into header.php,side.php etc.. ).It increases readability and make simpler to edit.Will it lead to increase interpreting time or similar issues ?

Comment: The difference should be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

There has been heaps of tests done on this and you shouldn't take parsing time into consideration, it will be minimal and the benefits of readability outweigh the negatives.

If you're worried about the time taken to open and read files you might want to look at a compiler such as [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) so the files are kept in a compiled state in memory.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be an issue, and even if it did, it is much more important to have maintainable code.

If you can break up your code in smaller independend classes, and use autoloading for this classes, it could even become faster, because only the necessary code needs to be loaded. Instead of just splitting your code to files and rejoining it with `include_once`, i would try to build such classes.

Answer (score 1):

Difference will be negligible. Php can handle that efficiently. Try also object oriented code is more readable. If you are that much worried about increased time, then i will suggest you to use caching like varnish or APC etc. It is not even required to call interpreters every time. Many time you interpret the code and cache it. only when you change the code, clear the cache and you have fresh page.